# get previous url before redirect

Tags: javascript, referrer

I thought that if I used `document.referrer` I could get the previous url of  a pageview.

Looks like this is the case when just browsing around pages within a site.

We have a redirect set up via an ad platform. I was asked if I could track whether or not all traffic to the end result landing page are following this redirect as they should be.

If the final page contains a parameter that I can listen for e.g. `?promo=via50` then `document.referrer` to to check the previous redirect URL.

But I tried this and the result of `document.referrer` is just `""`.

Is there a way to capture the redirect url?

URL test case in question [here](https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/trackclk/N120401.2134100VIARAIL/B9088936.125778075;dc_trk_aid=298696039;dc_trk_cid=67154314). So I would like to return the referring url `"https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/..."` and can trigger the Javascript whenever someone lands on the final redirected page.

Is this possible?

Comment: So does the adpage directly send the user to the page where you can listen to the promo variable? Also does the 'via50' not correspond to the ad platform that redirected the traffic?

Comment: Hi @Glubus. This is within the context of those wonderful banner ads that we all like and keep the internet lit up. A user will see an ad somewhere which will have the href attribute of the url contained in "here" part of my question above which will then redirect them to our site. Does this info help? Let me know if I can provide more information

Comment: What do you mean by "here" part. And I still don't get it (forgive me I've never dealt with these ad redirections on any of my web endeavors). This is what makes sense to me: A banner holds your websites url in a href attribute. So when a user clicks the banner he will be redirected to your page, which has the promo=via50 thing. So when that happens, you could just look in your database which url belongs to that promo variable

Comment: Hi @Glubus rather than paste the url in comment box if you see the sentence in my original post "URL test case in question here". So I would click the word "here" to see what's going on. If you have adblock enabled you won't see the clickable link.

Comment: I see, I guess Im not able to further help you then... I figured you could use the ?promo variable to find out where the redirect came from, but it seems that you instead want to couple the referring url with the promo variable... Im sorry for wasting your time, I have no experience with the javascript side of this question.

Comment: Thanks all the same @Glubus